# 'On board' as a complex PP

Tags: parts-of-speech

Consider the below sentence.

> On board the ship there is a crew of wise men.

To which category of speech does 'board' belong in the above sentence? Insofar as I understand, 'board' is a constituent of the complex prepositional phrase 'on board', analogous to 'according' in 'according to', 'owing' in 'owing to', etc.

Comment: _On board_ is the same construction as _aboard_, though printed and pronounced differently. Which shows how complex prepositions get somewhat less complex.

Comment: @Eric Yes, a complex preposition. The two parts cannot be separated.